# How do I set Windows PowerShell ISE default theme?

Tags: windows, powershell, colors, color-theme, powershell-ise

Whenever I change the theme in the PowerShell ISE options on Windows 10 to Light on Light it doesn't keep it when I restart, it goes back to the default Dark on Light. How can I set/force Light on Light to be my default?

(Also, setting the colors in a startup script causes it to flash to the default Dark on Light theme before it runs the script, but then the command line still has the original colors even though the rest of the console has the new colors.)

Comment: I've not seen this ever happen on any system where I or others I know / work with. It would be worth the effort to record this to show this real time. Yet, this comes off as environmental, something on your system, is hampering the setting from sticking. I have several theme loaded, my current is the Visual Studio 2013 Dark theme, and it sticks as expected.

Comment: @postanote as a wild shot in the dark, is it possible some color setting from (regular) PowerShell overriding ISE's? I messed with colors over there before switching to ISE. If so, where would those be stored?

Comment: See my thoughts on what you can do to get back to normal and the try your theme again.

Comment: [The **ISE Color Theme Cmdlets** script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ISE-Color-Theme-Cmdlets-24905f9e) could help.

Answer (score 0):

The console host and ISE color control are different animals for different use cases really.

The console shown in the ISE is not the same as the normal stand alone PS console. It's really noting more than an output windows that allows for additional interactive use cases.

You can reset the consolehost colors back to the default using

In the consolehost use

```
[Console]::ResetColor() 
Set-PSReadlineOption -ResetTokenColors
```

In the ISE options, just select restore default or run this command in the ISE,

```
$psISE.Options.RestoreDefaultTokenColors()
```